# AngularJs bind to select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular `1.5.2` and I'm trying to bind ,my `select` like this:

```
<label>Role</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <select id="role" class="form-control" name="role" >
            <option value="1" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.RoleId" name="role" id="intern">Stagiair</option>
            <option value="3" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.RoleId" name="role" id="employee">Werknemer</option>
            <option value="4" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.RoleId" name="role" id="companyadmin">Bedrijfadmin</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it's not working. When a user has role 4 it still shows 1 ?

Comment: The ng-model should be on the select tag, and it looks a bit strange. Can you post your controller code and show where you initiate this variable?

Answer (score 2):

you should use `ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.RoleId"` in `select` tag instead of `option` tag

```
   <select id="role" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.RoleId" >
        <option value="1" name="role" id="intern">Stagiair</option>
        <option value="3" name="role" id="employee">Werknemer</option>
        <option value="4" name="role" id="companyadmin">Bedrijfadmin</option>
    </select>
```

See [PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SbuC5GgGkVd4KkOz1Na5?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `ngModel` on the `select` element:

```
<select id="role" class="form-control" name="role" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.RoleId">
    <option value="1" name="role" id="intern">Stagiair</option>
    <option value="3" name="role" id="employee">Werknemer</option>
    <option value="4" name="role" id="companyadmin">Bedrijfadmin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Then the selected role is nothing. I've checked employeeCtrl.employee.RoleId and that is 4 so I would expect Bedrijfadmin to be selected.